# ngFor iteration using a unique key

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular5

HTML

```
   <li*ngFor="let data of employeeData"> {{data.name}} </li>;
```

JSON Data

```
   [{employeeID: "123",
    name : "abc",
    gender: "F"},

  {employeeID: "345",
   name : "def",
   gender: "F"}
   ]
```

I'd like to display only employee name whose employeeID is 345. How can I acheive this? Do I need to use a pipe?

Comment: You can do `ngIf="data.employeeID == 345`

Comment: Don't do business logic in the template. The component should *find* the item that needs to be displayed and the template displays it. Don't use `*ngFor` just to display *one* item in an array.

Comment: Basically, I have a dropdown with employee names, when I select an employee, I need to display data specific to that employee.  Employee names dropdown holds employeeID value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to show a selected user data, you don't actually need the ngFor, you can do something like:

```
users = [
    {employeeID: "123",
    name : "abc",
    gender: "F"},
    {employeeID: "345",
    name : "def",
    gender: "F"}
]

selectedUser = users.find((user) => user.employeeID == "345");

<li> {{selectedUser.name}} </li>;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to build a filter function to filter to the employee you want. Then you don't really need the `*ngFor`.

I have a blog post about filtering here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/filtering-in-angular/